# Return value from PowerShell function

Tags: function, powershell

I am writing a function to determine our reboot cycle.  It works, but I can't get it to return a value (should be a 1 or a 2). What might I be doing wrong?

```
function Get-BootCycle {
    $devEarliest  =  8
    $devLatest    = 14
    $prodEarliest = 15
    $prodLatest   = 21

    $today = Get-Date

    switch ($today.DayOfWeek) {
        Wednesday {$val = 1}
        Thursday  {$val = 2}
        Friday    {$val = 3}
        Saturday  {$val = 4}
        Sunday    {$val = 5}
        Monday    {$val = 6}
        Tuesday   {$val = 7}
    }

    $dateVal = "'" + [string]$val + "." + ([string]$today.Hour) + "." +
               $today.AddMinutes(-($today.Minute % 30)).Minute + "'"

    if ($today.Day -ge ($devEarliest + $val) -and $today.Day -le ($devLatest + $val)) {
        $bootCycle = "Development"
        $bootCycleVal = 0
    }
    elseif ($today.Day -ge ($prodEarliest + $val) -and $today.Day -le ($prodLatest + $val)) {
        $bootCycle = "Production"
        $bootCycleVal = 1
    }
    else {
        Break
    }
    return $bootCycleVal
}
```

Comment: FWIW you can just cast `[int]($today.DayOfWeek)` instead of using the swtich

Comment: I was aware of that, but I number the days based on our (Microsoft's) patch week cycle, so I needed the week to start on Wednesday.

Comment: Sorry didnt see that at first. Still I would use this: `([int](Get-Date).DayOFWeek + 5) % 7`

Comment: That's helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because neither of your conditions are returning true.

Essentially you're running into..

if(10 >= 11 AND 10 <= 17)... **returns false**

elseif( 10 >= 18 AND 10 <= 24) **returns false**

else Break **Hitting here and breaking**

Comment: Ah, my bad.  The function works, but this is not currently a dev or prod week.  Thanks for your help.